# Inconsistency in keyboard navigation for CBS_DROPDOWN and CBS_DROPDOWNLIST combo boxes

Tags: windows, winapi, combobox, usability

Combo boxes operate in 3 different modes: Simple, Dropdown, and Dropdown List. Dropdown (`CBS_DROPDOWN`) and Dropdown List (`CBS_DROPDOWNLIST`) are visually very similar. The only difference is that the Dropdown List style limits user input to the options available from the dropdown list while the Dropdown style doesn't impose any restrictions on user input.

With respect to keyboard navigation they operate slightly differently: While the Dropdown List style expands the dropdown list only when pressing the `Arrow Down` key, the Dropdown style also allows to use the `Arrow Up` key to expand the dropdown list. The default behavior listed under [Combo Box Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775793.aspx#default_behavior) explains how `WM_KEYDOWN` messages are handled differently:

> Processes noncharacter keyboard input. In drop-down list boxes, this message is sent to the list window, which may show or hide itself, or change its current selection or caret index. In simple and drop-down combo boxes, this message is passed to the edit control. The edit control passes certain keys to the list window, such as the UP and DOWN ARROW keys and the F4 key.

My question: Is this inconsistency in keyboard navigation intentional and what is the rationale behind this design decision, or is it simply an oversight in the implementation?

Comment: Arrow Down doesn't seem to drop the list for me (with a `CBS_DROPDOWNLIST` style control), it just scrolls through the options in the list.

Comment: @Jonathan: I forgot to mention, this is using the extended UI ([CB_SETEXTENDEDUI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775905.aspx)).